# How do you find a chat room that doesn’t appear when you click on it?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Hey guys I really want to find this chat room from u/Valerio Pastore.

[image]

But like, I can’t find it. I really want to view the messages on here, so how do I find it?

Answer (score 5):

Chatrooms with only a few messages are [automatically deleted after 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159976/295232). I can see them because I'm a moderator elsewhere in the Stack Exchange network; I don't think there's much harm in sharing it:

[image]